# Retrieving Data and Row count with doctrine in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Am not too familiar with `Doctrine::` queries in Symfony, but I need to modify a database query. This is the original code below:

```
function getUserById($userId) {
     try {
        return Doctrine :: getTable('UserDetails')->find($userId);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new DaoException($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

I want to add another field (status) to where clause the query. I tried

```
return Doctrine :: getTable('UserDetails')->find($userId)->andWhere('status=1');
```

But it did not work.
Please what do i do and how can I also return the number of rows that were affected by a select statement.

Comment: can you provide the exactly version of symfony and doctrine? Seem you refer to symfony1 with doctrine1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doctrine class with static method seem refer to same old version of the orm framework.

BTW You can try call the `findBy` passing an array of where condition.

In your case try this:

`return Doctrine :: getTable('UserDetails')->findBy(array('userId' =>$userId, 'status' => 1));`

Hope this help

Comment: Hi @Toni please consider to upvote my answer if you find it useful